# How can I fix yaml error: Block mapping value not allowed here

Tags: yaml, semaphore-ci

I copied Semaphore's [config](https://goreleaser.com/ci/semaphore/) of GoReleaser and saved it as `.semaphore/semaphore.yml` but when I run it on Semaphore, I can see:

```
Unprocessable YAML file.
Error: {{:throw, {:yamerl_exception, [{:yamerl_parsing_error, :error, 'Block mapping value not allowed here', 30, 20, :block_mapping_value_not_allowed, :undefined, []}]}}, "# .semaphore/semaphore.yml.\nversion: v1.0\nname: Build\nagent:\n machine:\n type: e1-standard-2\n os_image: ubuntu1804\n\nblocks:\n - name: \"Test\"\n task:\n prologue:\n commands:\n # set go version\n - sem-version go 1.11\n - \"export GOPATH=~/go\"\n - \"export PATH=/home/semaphore/go/bin:$PATH\"\n - checkout\n\n jobs:\n - name: \"Lint\"\n commands:\n - go get ./...\n - go test ./...\n\n# On Semaphore 2.0 deployment and delivery is managed with promotions,\n# which may be automatic or manual and optionally depend on conditions.\npromotions:\n - name: Release\n pipeline_file: goreleaser.yml\n auto_promote_on:\n - result: passed\n branch:\n - \"^refs/tags/v*\"\n"}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this last part:

```yaml
promotions:
    - name: Release
       pipeline_file: goreleaser.yml
       auto_promote_on:
         - result: passed
           branch:
             - "^refs/tags/v*"
```

The indentation of `pipeline_file` and `auto_promote_on` is wrong – both need to be at the same level as `name`.